# Pass values to class

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to pass x and y coordinates to a constructor in a class using java.awt.Point. My main class is throwing an error saying "The constructor Quadrilateral(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) is undefined. I thought when passing to my constructor 'public Quadrilateral(Point... points)' i could pass the coordinates as a simple list. Can someone tell me where these few lines of code may be going wrong?

Main

```
import java.awt.Point;


    public class QuadrilateralTest
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Quadrilateral quadrilateral = new Quadrilateral(1, 1, 6, 2, 6, 9, 2, 7);
System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", quadrilateral);
        }
    }
```

Quadrilateral class

```
import java.awt.Point;


public class Quadrilateral
{
    //points contain x and y coordinates
    private Point point1;
    private Point point2;
    private Point point3;
    private Point point4;


    public Quadrilateral(Point... points)
    {
        point1 = new Point(1, 2);
        point2 = new Point(3, 4);
        point3 = new Point(5, 6);
        point4 = new Point(7, 8);       
    }

    //setters and getters
    public Point getPoint1()
    {
        return point1;
    }

    public Point getPoint2()
    {
        return point2;
    }

    public Point getPoint3()
    {
        return point3;
    }

    public Point getPoint4()
    {
        return point4;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
         return ("\nThe Points of the Quadrilateral are:\n " +
                getPoint1() +"," + getPoint2() +"," + getPoint3() + "," + getPoint4())+"\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: No, that's not how Java varargs work at all.

Comment: Hint: you're not passing coordinates in the statement `new Quadrilateral(1, 1, 6, 2, 6, 9, 2, 7);`.  Rather, you're passing 8 integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not make sense at all, you are having varargs Points parameter, but not using them in the constructor, you can replace this by no-arg constructor if you have no use for input parameters

```
 public Quadrilateral()
    {
        point1 = new Point(1, 2);
        point2 = new Point(3, 4);
        point3 = new Point(5, 6);
        point4 = new Point(7, 8);       
    }
```

and do in `main()`

```
Quadrilateral quadrilateral = new Quadrilateral();
```

If you want really want to pass and use parameters as varargs `Point`, make your constructor use the values of arguments:-

```
public Quadrilateral(Point... points){

if((points.length>0)&&(points[0]!=null)){ //make sure to check this condition to allow user to input any number of parameters
point1=points[0];
}

if((points.length>1)&&(points[1]!=null)){
point2=points[1];
}
.
.
}
```

and then you can write in `main()`:-

```
Point point1 =new Point(1,2);
Point point2 =new Point(1,2);
Quadrilateral quad=new Quadrilateral(point1,point2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor takes in a `varargs` of `Point` - you can't just pass in a bunch of `int`s. Try instantiating the `Point`s and passing them in.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be fixed as @Evan suggests, like this:

```
public Quadrilateral(Point... points)
{
    point1 = points[0];
    point2 = points[1];
    point3 = points[2];
    point4 = points[3];       
}
```

But as you can understand there will be a lot of problems.

If you need exactly 4 Points as we see in your constructor you shouldn't be using `varargs` at all. You should just get 4 different `Point` parameter.

```
public Quadrilateral(Point _point1, Point _point2, Point _point3, Point _point4)
{
    point1 = _point1;
    point2 = _point2;
    point3 = _point3;
    point4 = _point4;       
}
```

That way you will be forcing users to send exactly 4 `Point`s.

Comment: But what if user wants to input variable length arguments, for example he wants to instantiate only 2 points and rest he assumes will be set to default. In that case varargs will prove useful :)

Comment: The name of the class `Quadrilateral` declares that it will need 4 parameters. With `varargs` approach you tell the user that he can pass lots of points too even if we are not going to use them(which users will not know of). And that's not a good design practice. With four parameter approach he can do `null` checks, as `varargs` aproach wil need too.

Comment: Yes thats true, But since user is insisting on varargs.  But still dont you think its better to null check and ignore extra values in Quadilateral class rather than forcing user for 4 points and checking if user has passed null. I mean ofcourse you are right in this case, but there maybe some usecase where varargs will be more useful :)

Comment: Yes you are right too when saying "there maybe some usecase where varargs will be more useful" :) that's why there are `varargs` in programming languages in the first place . But this is not one of them I guess.

Comment: And other thing is, we are here to help solving the problems in the neatest way. Not only giving them what they want. They might be asking for wrong thing!

Comment: True, I got a bit carried away :p